# Swift - what is downcasting? why do i need to downcast the cell in tableview?

Tags: uitableview, swift, xcode6

The code below is to show the name of the cells in UItableview.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
            as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = "Spring \(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
}
```

There is a compiling error and Xcode suggests me to change the line 'as' into 'as!'-

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        as! UITableViewCell
```

May someone explains what is downcast and why do we need to downcast in this case?

Comment: See [Downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) for the basic reasoning. Note that the method returns `AnyObject?` and thus the `as!` (why the `!`) is required - because the cast *may* fail. You could also use `as?` to handle failure inline. The [Apple iOS documentation also covers `as/as!/as?` usage in the Type Casting language section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK..lets make it very simple.

On the line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
```

You are accessing the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` of `tableView`, if you look at the documentation you can see the return type is `AnyObject?`.

Now suppose you want to access the `textLabel` property as

```
cell.textLabel!.text = "Spring \(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

You cannot do it..because there is no any `textlabel` on `AnyObject` the type.

So, you are downcasting to force compiler more specific class, `UITableViewCell`, as below because later you are trying to access text label property:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
```

Comment: I have downcast it but the tableview does not show the cell and its name.

Comment: Can i share it with you via dropbox? Maybe you can help to understand why?

Comment: so you click on spring and the add. After you submit, the table view is supposed to show spring 1, spring 2, and so forth if you add and submit again.

Comment: This is explanation is wrong - Firstly, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an `AnyObject?`, not a `UITableView` - the type returned doesn't depend on which type called it. Secondly, you cannot access the `textLabel` of an `AnyObject` (not a `UITableView`) because Swift doesn't know for sure that property exists on the object. Thirdly, you cannot downcast from a `UITableView` to a `UITableViewCell`. Try it in playgrounds - you'll get the warning: 'Cast from `UITableView` to unrelated type `UITableViewCell` always fails.'

Comment: That's better :) Except for the last part - you're still saying about downcasting from a `UITableView` to a `UITableViewCell`. I think you've got downcasting a bit mixed up.

Comment: Just a heads up in case you get confused: In Swift 3 and in the new Apple documentation, the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" function has been changed to return only a UITableViewCell and not AnyObject.

Answer (score 5):

Because `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `AnyObject` (`id` in Objective-C). Swift needs you to force downcast because `AnyObject` can be any object and by force casting, you're telling the compiler to disregard the current type and force cast to a more specific object down the inheritance line.

Comment: but what is the cause of downcasting possible from AnyObject to type of UITableViewCell..i really dont get it?

Comment: @copeME Your question doesn't make sense, could you rephrase it?

Comment: why were we able to downcast from AnyObject to class UITableViewCell?

Comment: @copeME because you're sure that in every situation, that object is an instance of `UITableViewCell`, but the compiler doesn't know that, so you force downcast it.

Answer (score 2):

As it reads in the [Official Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html), under downcasting:

> A constant or variable of a certain class type may actually refer to
> an instance of a subclass behind the scenes. Where you believe this is
> the case, you can try to downcast to the subclass type with a type
> cast operator (as? or as!).
>
> Use the forced form of the type cast
> operator (as!) only when you are sure that the downcast will always
> succeed. This form of the operator will trigger a runtime error if you
> try to downcast to an incorrect class type.

I hope this may answer your question ^_^

Comment: but what is the cause of downcasting possible from AnyObject to type of UITableViewCell..i really dont get it?

Answer (score 2):

As @Schemetrical said `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` return `AnyObject` but `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` need `UITableViewCell` to be returned.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
...
}
```

So if you return cell without downcast it, that won't match the method signature.

Comment: but what is the cause of downcasting possible from AnyObject to type of UITableViewCell..i really dont get it?