# What is the difference between these 2 type casting methods in swift

Tags: swift, casting, swift2

What is the difference between.. (Assuming this even is type casting)

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MessageCell
```

and

```
let cell:MessageCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

i know it seems basic, but i don't really know what i'm asking specifically enough to be able to look for the right resources to help me understand this.

Comment: One difference is that the first line compiles, while the second line does not compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - what is downcasting? why do i need to downcast the cell in tableview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116960/swift-what-is-downcasting-why-do-i-need-to-downcast-the-cell-in-tableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression is a *forced downcast*.

It's used in two cases:

- the return type is `AnyObject` and has to be casted to the proper type;
- the return type is a base class (`UITableViewCell`) and has to be casted to a subclass (`MessageCell`).

---

The second expression is not a type cast, it's a *type annotation*

It's used

- to declare the type if the type could not be inferred from the default value.

  From the documentation

  > It is rare that you need to write type annotations in practice. If you
  >   provide an initial value for a constant or variable at the point that
  >   it is defined, Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for
  >   that constant or variable

Comment: you answer is correct, no discussion! one note related to the question, the second statement from question will not compile, because (as you mention in your answer) the 'return type is a base class (UITableViewCell) and has to be casted to a subclass (MessageCell)'.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift,

While declaring variable dataType is optional part, if you initialise it.

e.g.

```
var intValue = 5;
```

In above case, it will store integer value and it's dataType will be Int.

If you later assign value to variable, you have to specify its dataType.
e.g.

```
var doubleValue : Double;
doubleValue = 2.0;
```

In your case

```
let cell:MessageCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

you are specifying dataType of `cell`, so if `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` will return `MessageCell` type, no need to caste it again.

but in
 `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MessageCell`

you have not specified dataType for `cell`, so in this case it will consider its dataType as `UITableViewCell` because return type of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is `UITableViewCell`.

But you have clear idea that it will return custom cell of type `MessageCell`, so to mention its dataType as `MessageCell` you have to forcefully unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

try to check next example in playground. properly understanding what casting is and how it works is an essential part of knowledge and if you are coming from C or ObjectiveC world, it could be very painful in the beginning ...

```
class B {
    func fb() {
        print("function defined in B.Type")
    }
}
class C: B{
    func fc() {
        print("function defined in C.Type")
    }
}
class D {}

func foo(t: Bool)->B! {
    if t {
        return C()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

let c0 = foo(true)
print("casting c0 is C returns:", c0 is C, " ,BUT c0 dynamic type is", c0.dynamicType)
// casting c0 is C returns: true, BUT c0 dynamic type is ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<B>
c0.fb() // function defined in B.Type

// but next line doesn't compile!! (try to 'uncomment it...)
//c0.fc() // error: value of type 'B' has no member 'fc'


let c1 = foo(true) as! C
c1 is C // compiler warns you that 'is' test always true :-)
c1.fb() // function defined in B.Type
c1.fc() // function defined in C.Type

// next lines don't compile !! (try to 'uncomment it...)
//let d0: D = foo(true) // error: cannot convert value of type 'B!' to specified type 'D'
//let c2: C = foo(true)    // error: cannot convert value of type 'B!' to specified type 'C'
```

...

```
// and finaly, next line compile with warning and (yes, unfortunately) crash :-)
let d = foo(true) as! D // crash you code
```